# querying child data-properties on RDF-store

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs

I have, in my ontology, an entity named "person" that has a class child named "member". Some like this (indenting for indicate the hierarchy),

```
person
    member
```

Also, I have some attributes (dataProperty), associated with "person", and another attributes associated with "member". Specifically, that attributes could be phone numbers. I propose a hierarchy of attributes in this way,

```
phone (domain: person)
    office-phone (domain: member)
        office-phone-1 (domain: member)
        office-phone-2 (domain: member)
    personal-phone (domain: person)
```

I'm doing the following,

```
SELECT ?s ?attr ?data
WHERE
{  
    value ?attr {:phone} .
    ?s rdf:type :member .
    ?s ?attr ?data .  
}
```

to get all phone-numbers,

```
instance-member   :phone   "value-of-personal-phone"
instance-member   :phone   "value-of-office-phone-1"
instance-member   :phone   "value-of-office-phone-2"
```

but,

how could I ONLY to get the two office-phone WITHOUT USE the specific attribute ":office-phone"?? Some owl:  restriction or definition??

Thanks!

Comment: With your sample data, this doesn't work. Indeed, you have to use the specific sub-properties first in your data. Then you could use a SPARQL query that considers only the subproperties of `office-phone`. In your current data this is only reflected in the literal string, nothing you could query based on the property hierarchy information. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to use the property hierarchy in your data, otherwise, this can't work (it would be good if you provide proper sample data next time...):

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema/> .

:officePhone rdfs:subPropertyOf :phone .
:officePhone1 rdfs:subPropertyOf :officePhone .
:officePhone2 rdfs:subPropertyOf :officePhone .
:personalPhone rdfs:subPropertyOf :phone .

:instance-member rdf:type :member .

:instance-member   :personalPhone   "value-of-personal-phone" .
:instance-member   :officePhone1   "value-of-office-phone-1" .
:instance-member   :officePhone2   "value-of-office-phone-2" .
```

Regarding the querying, there are at least two options:

1) The triple store supports reasoning, RDFS would be enough in your example - then your query would be sufficient.

2) You rewrite your query such that the property hierarchy is taken into account using SPARQL 1.1 property paths:

```sql
prefix : <http://example.org/>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema/>

SELECT ?s ?attr ?data
    WHERE
    {  
        values ?p {:officePhone} 
        ?s rdf:type :member .
        ?attr rdfs:subPropertyOf* ?p .
        ?s ?attr ?data .  
    }
```

Result:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| s                | attr          | data                      |
================================================================
| :instance-member | :officePhone1 | "value-of-office-phone-1" |
| :instance-member | :officePhone2 | "value-of-office-phone-2" |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: ...in agree... I forgot to include a sample data... sorry, and a lot of thanks, but are in the same way that you explain (and hierarchies defined in my ontology). But, my question was "...WITHOUT USE :office-phone..." If you use this dataProperty, YOU DON'T NEED to include the triple "?attr rdfs:subPropertyOf* ?p ."; it would be the same sparql that I included first, and I get the childs of "office-phone"...the question was to get properties relatives to "member" class only using the superproperty "phone"... Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

...I got it in a similar way, showing the superproperty, restrincting the domain and including a distinct...

```
SELECT distinct ?s ?attr_father ?data
WHERE
{ 
    values ?attr_father {:phone} .

    ?s rdf:type :member .
    ?attr rdfs:subPropertyOf* ?attr_father .
    ?attr rdfs:domain :member .
    ?s ?attr ?data .    
}
```

In this way, we get,

```
instance-member   :phone   "value-of-office-phone-1" .
instance-member   :phone   "value-of-office-phone-2" .
```

Regards!

Comment: Ok, but then your question did not reflect what you want, especially not with the sample data that you showed which wouldn't work with your query here and is far away from complete. I don't see why the triple `:instance-member   :personalPhone   "value-of-personal-phone" .` would not be returned with your query...

Comment: ...so, with domain restriction the query works in this way (with a sample of data as you writed... another time, sorry for forgetting write them). If you remove this triple in query, you get the third result "instance-member  :personal-phone  value-of-personal-phone"... Regards!